# Searching categories using AND and OR query in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I wonder is it possible to do where `(A OR B) AND (C)` operation in SQL?

For example, given Two tables
Fruits

```
+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
| 1  | Apple  |
+----+--------+
| 2  | Banana |
+----+--------+
| 3  | Cherry |
+----+--------+
```

Categories

```
+----+--------+------------+
| id |  name  | group_name |
+----+--------+------------+
| 1  | Red    |  colour    |
+----+--------+------------+
| 2  | Yellow |  colour    |
+----+--------+------------+
| 3  | Green  |  colour    |
+----+--------+------------+
| 4  | Round  |  shape     |
+----+--------+------------+
| 5  | Long   |  shape     |
+----+--------+------------+
```

And a join table

```
+----------+--------------+
| fruid_id |  category_id |
+----------+--------------+
|    1     |      1       | (Apple, Red)
+----------+--------------+
|    1     |      3       | (Apple, Green)
+----------+--------------+
|    1     |      4       | (Apple, Round)
+----------+--------------+
|    2     |      2       | (Banana, Yellow)
+----------+--------------+
|    2     |      5       | (Banana, Long)
+----------+--------------+
|    3     |      1       | (Cherry, Red)
+----------+--------------+
|    3     |      4       | (Cherry, Round)
+----------+--------------+
```

And I wish to filter all fruits that is ('Red' OR 'Yellow') AND ('Round').

The answer should be Apple and Cherry.

Comment: yes you can use any  combination of  or and any  in sql

Comment: Why don't you try and see the result ?

Comment: use `WHERE` clause on your query like this & try. `WHERE (Categories.name = 'Red' OR Categories.name = 'Yellow') AND Categories.name = 'Round'`.

Comment: While explaining try to add your query & if possible do a working example(fiddle) so that other can easily try to help you.

Comment: You should spell "color" consistently.

Comment: ...and fruit too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this as:

```
select f.*
from fruit f join
     fruit_categories fc
     on fc.fruit_id = f.id join
     categories c
     on fc.category_id = c.id
where (c.group_name = 'color' and c.name in ('Red', 'Yellow')) or
      (c.group_name = 'shape' and c.name in ('Round))
group by f.id
having count(distinct c.group_name) = 2;  -- both color and shape match
```

This does assume that "color" is spelled consistently in the data.

Answer (score 0):

try this out.

```
select  * from  fruit_category  fc
inner join  Categories c  on fc.category_id =c.id 
where     ((c.name = 'Red') or (c.name = 'Yellow'))  and    (category_id=4)
```

Comment: What if there's an orange shape, say?

Comment: See Gordon's answer